# Omitting type parameter for greater template in C++ STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, generic-programming, function-object

Here is a line of code I read in a book

```
priority_queue<IteratorCurrentAndEnd, vector<IteratorCurrentAndEnd>, greater<>> min_heap;
```

where `IteratorCurrentAndEnd` is a class implementing a `operator>` method. Why can we have `greater<>` instead of `greater<IteratorCurrentAndEnd>`? I checked and read something like this,

```
template< class T = void >
struct greater;
```

But I don't really know what it means. Is it something related to the `void` type? What is it actually?

Thanks.

Comment: This is easy to find from cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void . If you just google `std::greater`, cppreference's page on it comes up

Answer (score 7):

Until C++14, `std::greater<T>` was a class template based on one explicit type parameter `T`. It only allowed to compare two equal types. Otherwise, when comparing different types, one had to rely on conversion which can fail in the process of template argument deduction.

This has been fixed with C++14 in the sense that now there also exists a general comparison of two distinct types. Instead of using a new class template `std::greater<T,U>` (which possibly would not be backwards compatible and certainly also more complicate), a specialization `std::greater<void>` is used which did not exist before C++14. The type `void` is chosen for exactly this reason: as it was never used before C++14 -- comparison of `void`s makes no sense -- one automatically gets backwards compatibility and even avoids introducing a new class template.

As it's described in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void), `std::greater<void>` now is a functor containing an `operator()` function template similar to

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
{
    return std::forward<T>(lhs) > std::forward<U>(rhs);
}
```

This implements the general comparison between two types (and is quite the same as one would come up with nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is related to the `void` in the snippet, but it's nothing special about void as a type itself. This syntax says that `struct greater` takes one template parameter (that is a type), but that it can be omitted, and in case it is omitted, `void` is used as that type. It's similar to default value syntax for regular functions:

```
void foo(int x = 7);

foo(5); // x = 5
foo(); // x = 7
```